# How can i use Linq to calculate the total value and assign the result to a field?

Tags: c#, lambda

Is there a way I can make this code more compact with a lambda or an anonymous function or something like that?

```
static int chancesTotal = _total_chances();
static int _total_chances()
{
    int x = 0;
    foreach (var c in chances)
        x += c.Value;
    return x;
}
```

That is, I'd like something like

```
int chancesTotal = () =>
{
    int x = 0;
    foreach (var c in chances)
        x += c.Value;
    return x;
}();
```

But it doesn't work.

---

Edit: this solution proposed by @pinkfloydx33 is close to what I had asked.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


List<int> chances = new List<int>();

int chancesTotal = ((Func<int>)(() =>
{
    int x = 0;
    foreach (var c in chances)
        x += c;
    return x;
}))();
```

Comment: `return chances.Sum(c => c.Value)`

Comment: using `System.Linq`

Comment: Firstly, why do you need it more compact... and secondly, why haven't you looked at the documentation for enumerable, it's very easy to read

Comment: Fun fact,  linq doesn't mean faster, in a lot of cases it allocates because of the lambda and generated classes, and it does what you can do in in a loop yet less efficently, If you do want something more succinct then you should be looking st thr documentation

Comment: Here's the "equivalent" of what you say you want. Note that it's not very compact at all https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgAwFgBQiCM65IARyYAsA3OuWgDICWAzsADzVTAD8AfHgMYAWAhlC4BTWngC8eKEIDuACgCUZNOmbBu/QSIAqAe2B8ANuLyzZcAKxMW7eafnj26AN7o8bvKrwAPY0iXu8ADMdMCE+XhMANz4wbg8odQFhWnlXAPcfAGoJLgA6ADVDCCF/dzgAdm8lAF95W0UgA

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks that's the answer I was looking for. But you're right in that it isn't a very convenient alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int chancesTotal = chances.Sum(c => c.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in this case but I was looking for a more general answer.

Comment: @mg979 Ok, I understand. I don't believe there is a less verbose solution in C# than the one proposed by pinkfloydx33.